# Is the gamma function a solution to this problem?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, optimization, functional-equations, gamma-function

A real differentiable function on $\mathbb{R}^+$ satisfying $f(x) = x!$ for $x\in\mathbb{N}$ and having minimal derivative $\left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right|$ everywhere, say in the sense that it minimizes $$\left\|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right\|_k = \sqrt[k]{\int_{0}^\infty \left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right|^kdx}$$(For which k) will it be the (translated) gamma function?

(This is just a guess from me that there should be such a $k$.)

---

**Edit** as pointed out in the comments the integral above of course won't converge. Maybe we can replace it with $\left\|g\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)\right\|_k$ for $g(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ or $\log(x)$ or maybe switch to $\left\|\frac{dg(f)}{dx}\right\|$ like  logarithmic derivative ($g=\log$) some other function guaranteed to be integrable. Or to limit the original measure to an interval or a sequence of intervals

$$\left\|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right\|_k = \sqrt[k]{\int_{0}^{x_1} \left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right|^kdx}$$

Comment: IMO your integrals do not exist. Do you think about a special limiting process?

Comment: Yes of course you are right the derivative grows far too quick. I wonder how one could reformulate it. Maybe either reformulate it to be the power series expansion on a limited interval or instead minimizing the norm of a monotonic function $1/d(x)$.

Comment: Here are some functions interpolating $n!\,$ which seem to have 'smaller curvature': http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/hadamard/HadamardsGammaFunction.html

Comment: wow great link thank you.

Comment: @gammatester : yes but only because of the singularities at the negative integers ? $\Gamma(x)$ is analytic and all its derivatives are increasing on $[1,\infty[$ :   $\Gamma^{(k)}(x) = \int_0^\infty (\ln t)^k t^{x-1} e^{-t}dt > 0$ for every $x \ge 1$ hence I think that $\Gamma(x)$ is in some sense the "best" interpolation between the $n!, n \ge 1$